# Double clicking a link on my Rails site results in incorrect routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails site which I created using the standard `rails new` command, followed by `rails g controller [page] [index file]` command to general the view and controller for each new page. However, whenever I click multiple times on a link, or when I click on a link quickly followed by a different link before page load, I get a double/treble/etc routing; for example the following:

http://www.alisaesage.com/shaltayboltay/shaltayboltay/index

Which obviously results in a 404. This routing was reached from the index page, which has the following template code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="title">AlisaEsage.com</h1>
    <h2 class="master-sub">A Resource</h2>
    <h3 class="mini-sub">Info, forums, articles, resources etc, by, about and related to the Alisa "Esage" Shevchenko, story. The idea is to give a full and complete picture of the "U.S. certified Russian Hacker", her guilt or innocence, her motivations and goals, as well as those of her networks of influence, and any and all of her close associates and 'partners in crime'.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="list-box-outer">
    <div class="list-box-inner">
      <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="./aboutalisa/index">About Alisa</a></li>
        <li><a href="./shaltayboltay/index">Шалтай Болтай</a></li>
        <li>Operation Silk Scarf</li>
        <li><a href="./articles/index">Media Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="./social/index">Social Media</a></li>
        <li>Conspiracy Theories</li>
        <li><a href="./phrahacking/index">Hacking/Phracking etc</a></li>
        <li>Forums</li>
        <li>Puppies and Other Animals</li>
        <li><a href="./quotes/index">Quotes</a></li>
        <li><a href="./pics/index">Fashion/Pics</a></li>
        <li><a href="./geopolitics/index">Geopolitics</a></li>
        <li><a href="./fanfic/index">Poetry/Fanfic</a></li>
        <li>Contribute</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>Owned and maintained by re8e1d45</p>
</div>
```

And the following controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

(Yes, yes. Not very sophisticated stuff in the controller yet :-P). The routes file looks like this:

```
 # Basic Routings
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'geopolitics/index'

  get 'aboutalisa/index'

  get 'shaltayboltay/index'

  namespace :curious do
    get 'part1/index'
  end

  namespace :curious do
    get 'part2/index'
  end

  get 'part2/index'

  get 'political/index'

  get 'manifestos/index'

  get 'fanfic/index'

  get 'pics/index'

  get 'quotes/index'

  get 'contributions/index'

    get 'phrahacking/index'
    get 'puppies/index'
    get 'social/index'
    get 'articles/index'
    get 'nineteeneightyfour/hidden'
    get 'home/index'

    get '/defaultsite' => 'home#index'
    get '/' => 'home#index'

    resources :articles

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'home#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So, there's quite a bit going on here.

First, each of those gets in your routes will be looking for a controller of the same name. You only have 1 so that's why it's not finding it. If all of those are models you are trying to view, you'll need to make a controller for every one(and a model for each one). There's a lot more wrong here, so instead of typing out a 5 paragraph explanation, are you following a tutorial for rails or just striking out on your own and trying to figure out what to do?

Comment: I have a whole bunch of controllers, one for each route, which I generated with `rails g controller` each time. I didn't reproduce them all because there are so many. I don't need a model yet as the views are not dynamic (though I will be making them dynamic later). I was following a few different guides, looking things up here and there, as I needed to.

Comment: Okay, well, there's some changes that need to happen. First, in your routes file, instead of get 'quotes/index' change it to 'resources :quotes' which will give you all the paths for your quotes model, you can limit that to just the index later if you dont want new/create/edit/update/destroy/show. This will give you a bunch of paths to use which you can find by running 'rake routes' in command line. Basically, if you want to get the index page for quotes, it would be quotes_path.

Comment: I figured. What are they?

Comment: So, in your view, to link to the quotes index page, you'd use a rails helper method called [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to). In your view up there, instead of <a href=...etc> It would just be <%= link_to 'Quotes', quotes_path %> where 'Quotes' is the text the user would see.

Comment: Note, I'm assuming you've made a Quote model, i.e. 'rake g model Quote'

Comment: I used `rails g controller` for everything, including the quotes section. I just wanted to have the website up and running quickly because I wanted to focus on content. I thought rake was to do with databasing.

Comment: What does `<%= link_to 'Quotes', quotes_path %>` do differently that would solve the problem? Could you add this to your answer?

Comment: Well for one, there's no such thing as a URL quotes/index. I'll let this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951582/why-does-rails-use-helper-methods-like-link-to-instead-of-a-href) explain the rest.

Comment: Sorry, and as far as the model goes, no 'rails g controller' just generates a controller, it has nothing to do with a model.

Comment: I'd also suggest working through [this](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) entire tutorial because you don't really seem to have a grasp on how MVC and rails works at the most basic level.

Comment: You're not understanding, you don't have any grasp of the rails framework and how it interacts with different parts. What I'm saying is, you need to learn how to build a complete MVC workflow. It's not something you can just piece together based off of stackoverflow answers. What you're asking isn't a quick fix that can be changed in a line or two. You need to know how to properly implement a model, initialize the model objects in the controller and how to write them in your views, all along maintaining your routes file correctly. None of which you've done.

Comment: I've used MVC for the last two years. I don't want to understand View Model Controller or the various derivations thereof. I want to know why Rails is reacting to multiple clicks in the way it is. It's not an MVC conceptualisation problem.

Comment: If you are getting the page that no route can be found, that's an MVC problem.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the entire question. Perhaps a problem with my wording? The routing works fine for a single click. It's multiple clicks before page-load that are the problem.